# How to destroy comboboxes if they are available in python gui?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I have a function, which based on the count generates the comboboxes. I want to destroy any combobox which is available already whenever my count variable changes. I used winfo_exists to do this...but it throws an attribute error every time. Please help me with this.

Here is the code of that function:

```
def create(event):
        count = combo.current()
        print ("count")
        print(count)

        for i in range(1,count+2):

            if (create_combo[i].winfo_exists()):
                create_combo[i].destroy()


        for i in range (1,count+2):

            create = tk.StringVar()

            create_combo[i]= ttk.Combobox(new_window_2,width = 15,textvariable = create, values = sheets)
            #create_combo.set("Sheet " + str(i))
            create_combo[i].grid(column = i, row =4, padx=10,pady=10)
```

Comment: Try to show a minimal example of your code.

Comment: THis is the error I get when i run : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'winfo_exists'

Comment: What's the `create_combo`?I really don't know what do you want to do.

Comment: create_combo is the name of the Combobox widget of tkinter,ttk

Comment: If `create_combo` is a `Combobox` widget,why do you use `create_combo[i]`?`i` should be string instead of an integer.Else it will also raise `TypeError`.Or `create_combo` is a list full of `Combobox`?

Comment: i am creating multiple comboboxes at a go by using this for loop. I should be able to control each and every combobox created....that's why i am using an array to create these multiple comboboxes

Comment: So `create_combo` is a list,right?

Comment: yeah...create_combo is a list.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the widgets which are created in loop, can be deleted by using the method available in this link
[Python Tkinter :removing widgets that were created using a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977885/python-tkinter-removing-widgets-that-were-created-using-a-for-loop)

This worked for me... I dont understand why winfo_exists didn't work.
Anyway Thanks!!

```
list_of_owner_widgets = []
 def create(event):
        count = combo.current()
        print(count)

        for widget in list_of_owner_widgets:
            widget.destroy()

        for i in range (1,count+2):

            create = tk.StringVar()
            create_combo[i]= ttk.Combobox(new_window_2,width = 15,textvariable = create, values = sheets)
            list_of_owner_widgets.append(create_combo[i])
            create_combo[i].grid(column = i, row =4, padx=10,pady=10)
```

Comment: Try to edit and show me how did you use this answer to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your post:

```
for i in range(1,count+2):
    if (create_combo[i].winfo_exists()):
        create_combo[i].destroy()
```

And the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'winfo_exists'
```

I can infer that:Your `create_combo` must be a list full of string(Instead of `Combobox` widget).

You could add `print(create_combo)` before the first for loop to check the value in `create_combo`.It must be a list full of string.

---

And it seems that your problem is not here,you should check the way how you create the `create_combo`.

---

> lets assume create_combo = ['a','b','c']. So I am creating three comboboxes create_combo[0...2]. So name of the comboboxes(widgets) is a, b, c.

No,you couldn't.

If really want to get a list of comboboxes you create,you should use:

```
create_combo = []
for i in range(3):
    t = ttk.Combobox(xxxxx)
    t.grid(xxxxxx)
    create_combo.append(t) # append it to your create_combo
```

And then,you could use:

```
for i in create_combo:
    if i.winfo_exists(): # i should be a widget,not string
        xxxxxxx # your job
```

Comment: yeah....create_combo is a list of strings...Only by using this method I will be able to create comboboxes in a loop and still gain control over each combobox....

Comment: @PriyaRamakrishnan That's must be the cause.`winfo_exists` should be used to a `widget`.Not a `string`.That's why it will raise `'str' object has no attribute 'winfo_exists'`.If now you use `list_of_owner_widgets` you posted,it won't raise error.

Comment: lets assume create_combo = ['a','b','c']. So I am creating three comboboxes create_combo[0...2]. So name of the comboboxes(widgets) is a, b, c and in that case a.winfo_exists should provide me true or false depending on whether the widget is available or not right?

Comment: @PriyaRamakrishnan edited,`'a'` is not `a`.`'a'` is a string object.In your example,it like `'a'.winfo_exists()`.You could do `a=ttk.combobox(xxx)` and `a.winfo_exists`.

Comment: just wanted to know....in that case what could be the possible way to know whether the widget exists or not using winfo_exists when widgets are created using loops....

Comment: I have already provided you a way to use for loop to create widget,and use winfo_exists to check it.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to destroy a Python widget, be it a Checkbox in your case, you use the following code.

**It is a lot easier to remove and show widgets using the .grid method!**

Your code:

```
create_combo[i].destroy()
```

I assume (as I can see further down the code file) that you used the grid method. In which case I would simply change the code to:

```
create_combo[i].grid_forget()
```

Hope This Helps!

Comment: Then raised the error:`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'winfo_exists'`.